# Different values for snapshot component name in development and production

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the code below that is supposed to return component's name for current route's first child:

```
let comp = this.route.snapshot.firstChild.component;
comp = typeof comp === 'string' ? comp : comp.name;
```

In development (`ng serve`) `comp`'s value is what it's supposed to be:

If url is `localhost:4200/A?asd=1` `comp` will be equal to `AComponent` since route `A` points to `AComponent`,

but in production (`ng build --prod`) `comp`'s value becomes some uglified parameter name like `t` or `r`

The question is how is `firstChild.component` being set that the value changes in production, and what is a more stable way to get routes' child component name

Comment: The answer is in the question: in production, you uglify your code, and the name of the functions is thus uglified. If you told ud what you actually want to achieve, we could probably help you do it in a correct way.

Comment: @JBNizet I need a way to do what I already can do in development, get component name of current route's first child

Comment: Then don't uglify your code,as you're doing in development.

Comment: @JBNizet That's just a lazy solution, I'm not gonna change something that should not have any impact on logic of your code just because one of angular's own libraries behave differently based on the environment you're in. It should work the same, since it's not I'm looking for a legit solution

Comment: I asked what you actually want to achieve in order to be able to suggest a better way to do it, but you refused to answer... You chose a solution to solve a problem, refuse to tell us what the problem is, and complain that your solution is not good. We can't help if you don't tell what the problem is. Typical XY issue. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @JBNizet "get component name of current route's first child" that is the problem, and I also want to know why the current solution is not working.

Comment: No, that's not the problem. That's the solution you chose to solve the actual problem you're having. Your customer never asked you to "print the name of the first child component when you click that button". He told you to do something that makes sense for an end user, but you won't tell us what. I told you why the solution to your unknown problem doesn't work: because comp.name is the name of the JavaScript function used to implement the component, and the function name is uglified in production.

Comment: @JBNizet "JavaScript function used to implement the component, and the function name is uglified in production" there you go, that actually makes sense. I thought `.name` was a parameter of component. I didn't know it was something that js does. thanks